# Smart Servo Shield: How to upload code to AtMega8

Tags: servo

I recently bought a Smart Servo Shield controller from DFrobot to use with my new AX-12A Dynamixel servos. The shield is attached to an Arduino Uno. The shield itself works fine, but it does not support all of the functions that I need. The shield has an AtMega8 on board, and they also give you the slave code that it runs to look over. If I were to modify said slave code, is there a way for me to upload to the shield's controller? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Smart Servo Shield
http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=958#.VfXqzxFVhBc

Answer (score 1):

[Like the wiki says](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Digital_Servo_Shield_for_Arduino_SKU:DRI0027#Pin_Out), remove the solder jumpers from the "UART SELECT" jumpers and connect to the "UART FOR Atmega8" connector in order to program it via serial. Don't forget to replace the solder jumpers after.

If you want to use ISP instead then make sure to remove the shield from the Arduino first since the shield connects all the ATmega8 ISP lines directly to the Arduino ISP lines.